# How to get more than two values in android listview selection

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I want to open an activity depends on the value user select on a ListView. If user select a list item that have type1 value it should open acitvity1 (activity1.class), if the list item belongs to type2 it should open acitvity2 (activity2.class). I still wants to get the id value.
Can some one please help me to get more than one values in a list. (not just the id value) or a work around for this.

following is my code;

```
            @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            //TODO:need to assign the value here 
            String mEdit = .......;

            if (mEdit.equals("type1")){
                Intent i = new Intent(this, activity1.class);
                i.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id );
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
            }else if (mEdit.equals("type2")){
                Intent i = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
                i.putExtra(KEY_ROWIDA, id );
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
            };

            }
```

> Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call getListView().getItemAtPosition(int) on your ListActivity and give it the index of the list item. You can then cast it to whatever the backing object is and perform any operations on that Object. Example from one of my own apps:

```
ForumDescriptor selected = (ForumDescriptor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
```

ForumDescriptor has some information about an individual subforum (it's a forums viewer for a website). Each one is an item in my list.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm new to this...    
   
                         should i use it after super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ida);                 @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long ida) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ida);
    
    showToast("id= " + getListView().getItemAtPosition(1) +"   ");

Comment: I think you are a little confused. The ForumDescriptor object named selected has a method that I can get a URL from. In your case you would probably want each list item to be an Object that either launches the Activity or returns the class to use in startActivityForResult()

Comment: Thank you very much.      It is working now. I have use following     @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long ida) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ida);
 
    Cursor mycursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
    showToast("mycursor.getString(1) " + mycursor.getString(1) +"   ");

Answer (score 0):

This could work on the situation,

```
...    
//TODO:need to assign the value here 
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
        String category = tv.getText().toString();
...
```

The 'R.id.itemname' is the id attribute of list item defined in layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the working code;

```
            @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //TODO:need to assign the value here 
        Cursor mycursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position); 
        //1 is the field position
        String mEdit = mycursor.getString(1);

        if (mEdit.equals("type1")){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, activity1.class);
            i.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id );
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }else if (mEdit.equals("type2")){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
            i.putExtra(KEY_ROWIDA, id );
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        };

        }
```